# mongodb update the value for all keys based on a python function

Tags: python, datetime, mongodb, pymongo

I am using pymongo

I have a mongo db in which all documents have a 
"timestamp" : "25-OCT-2011"

So a string is stored in the key `timestamp` in all documents.

I want to apply a python function as mentioned below on these string dates and convert them into a datetime object. What's the best way to do this in mongodb?

```
import datetime
def make_date(str_date):  
    return datetime.datetime.strptime(str_date, "%d-%b-%Y")
```

Answer (score 1):

To fit your needs:

```
import bson    

for document in list(database.collection.find({ })):
   converted_date = make_date(document['timestamp'])
   database.collection.update(
         { "_id": bson.objectid.ObjectId(document['_id']) },
         { "converted": converted_date }
   )
```

I use the ObjectId as a query to be sure that I update the document that I just got. I do that because I'm unsure whether timestamp collisions would lead to unwanted consequences.

Comment: I need to save the changes in the mongodb too